# How to consume grouped sub streams with mapAsync in akka streams

Tags: scala, stream, akka-stream

I need to do something really similar to this https://github.com/typesafehub/activator-akka-stream-scala/blob/master/src/main/scala/sample/stream/GroupLogFile.scala

my problem is that I have an unknown number of groups and if the number of parallelism of the mapAsync is less of the number of groups i got and error in the last sink

> Tearing down
>   SynchronousFileSink(/Users/sam/dev/projects/akka-streams/target/log-ERROR.txt)
>   due to upstream error
>   (akka.stream.impl.StreamSubscriptionTimeoutSupport$$anon$2)

I tried to put a buffer in the middle as suggested in the pattern guide of akka streams http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/scala/stream-cookbook.html

```
groupBy {
  case LoglevelPattern(level) => level
  case other                  => "OTHER"
}.buffer(1000, OverflowStrategy.backpressure).
  // write lines of each group to a separate file
  mapAsync(parallelism = 2) {....
```

but with the same result

Comment: I wonder if using `mapAsync` serves any purpose in the first place? What happens if you just use `map` instead?

Comment: with map the groups are not consumed in parallel / async which is my desired behavior

Comment: I think that's a misconception. All of the groups are represented by a `Source[Something]` (after `groupBy` you have a `Source[Source[Something]]`, right?). So, the only thing you need to do inside of the `map` (`foreach` should work as well) would be to run the subflows which is an asynchronous operation. The subflows would then run on their own and your `map` element would be free to accept the next `Source[Something]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on jrudolph's comment which is completely correct...

You do not need a `mapAsync` in this instance.  As a basic example, suppose you have a source of tuples

```
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Source, Sink}

def data() = List(("foo", 1),
                  ("foo", 2),
                  ("bar", 1),
                  ("foo", 3),
                  ("bar", 2))

val originalSource = Source(data)
```

You can then perform a groupBy to create a [Source of Sources](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/The_Source)

```
def getID(tuple : (String, Int)) = tuple._1

//a Source of (String, Source[(String, Int),_])
val groupedSource = originalSource groupBy getID
```

Each one of the grouped Sources can be processed in parallel with just a `map`, no need for anything fancy.  Here is an example of each grouping being summed in an independent stream:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ACtorMaterializer

implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()
import actorSystem.dispatcher

def getValues(tuple : (String, Int)) = tuple._2

//does not have to be a def, we can re-use the same sink over-and-over
val sumSink = Sink.fold[Int,Int](0)(_ + _)

//a Source of (String, Future[Int])
val sumSource  = 
  groupedSource map { case (id, src) => 
    id -> {src map getValues runWith sumSink} //calculate sum in independent stream
  }
```

Now all of the `"foo"` numbers are being summed in parallel with all of the `"bar"` numbers.

`mapAsync` is used when you have a encapsulated function that returns a `Future[T]` and you're trying to emit a `T` instead; which is not the case in you question.  Further, mapAsync involves [waiting for results](https://www.google.com/search?q=coyote%20mid%20air%20images) which is not [reactive](http://www.reactivemanifesto.org)...

Comment: Now that akka streams has been merged with akka and the Source of Sources semantics have been replaced with SubFlows, how would one accomplish a similar behavior?

Comment: @AlphaGeek I noticed that the groupBy functionality changed a couple of months back.  The cookbook has an updated example based on the new substreams approach: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/scala/stream/stream-cookbook.html#Implementing_reduce-by-key

Comment: @RamonJRomeroyVigil Cookbook doesn't explain it. They use reduce which is unfuasible if we have mullions of items in each substream. What I (and author too) want is to get `Source` per group. How would we do that ?

Comment: Was there ever a resolution on this?

Comment: @Zee Unfortunately the new implementation of substreams does not pass the key  that is associated with the substream.  Therefore, I don't know how to generate the output asked for in the question...

Comment: Is this the same as `originalSource.groupBy(..).map(...).async`? i.e. each group's map function will be executed in a separate thread?

Comment: @RamónJRomeroyVigil https://algd.github.io/akka/2018/08/05/parallel-stream-processing.html - This post says otherwise (see the last 2 sections)